# How to complete or terminate process after certain amount of time in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to execute a command and I want to let the process complete or terminate it after certain amount of time (e.g. after 20 minutes). This is what I have tried so far:

```
def proc =["/bin/sh", "-c","command"].execute()
proc.waitFor(1200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
StringBuffer outputStream = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
String output = outputStream.toString()
```

Even though I set `proc.waitFor(1200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, the process does not stop and it continues execution after 20 minutes timeout. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy provides a method call [**`Process.waitForOrKill(long numberOfMillis)`**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.15/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html#waitForOrKill-java.lang.Process-long-) you could use to simulate a timeout of a process. This method does what it says - it waits for the process to finish during a certain amount of time, or destroys the process otherwise. It is worth mentioning that if process is killed due to timeout, stream got closed and you will get `IOException` when trying to read from it (including checking if stream is available with `proc.inputStream.available()`). That's why it is important to run such code in try-catch.

Consider following example:

```
import java.time.LocalTime

try {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Start..."

    def proc = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 5s && echo 'test'"].execute()

    proc.waitForOrKill(2 * 1000)

    def output = proc.text?.trim()

    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Output = ${output}"

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("[${LocalTime.now()}] Process killed before completing!")
} finally {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] End..."
}
```

This is very simple process that sleeps for 5 seconds and echoes 'test' to the console. In this example I give this process 2 seconds to complete, which causes this process to fail before completing:

```
[08:30:04.116] Start...
[08:30:06.198] Process killed before completing!
[08:30:06.214] End...
```

But if I increase the timeout to let's say 10 seconds, the process completes successfully after approximately 5 seconds:

```
[08:30:39.582] Start...
[08:30:44.655] Output = test
[08:30:44.656] End...
```

Hope it helps.